# how to add class in ul and li at html5blank_nav()?

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I tried to add classes in ul li and a how to add classes on ul and li if using html5blank templates at html5blank_nav ().
how to add classes on ul and li if using html5blank templates at html5blank_nav()?

Answer (score 0):

I use html5blank theme too.
If you open the functions.php file you will find this

```
function html5blank_nav() {
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Then you can edit the way is calling the wp_nav_menu to add class to the ul.

To add styles to the li you must go to wordpress admin and edit the menu

1. Go to admin > appearance > menu
2. Click on Screen Options (top right of the screen)
3. Check the CSS classes options in the “Show advanced menu properties” panel
4. Add your css classes to the element

I hope that's what you need

Comment: does it help you?